# Catalyst 12.1 for AGP card

Tags: ati, graphics, fglrx

I have a Radeon HD 4650 AGP card. The installation instructions at http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide download catalyst 12.1

However, there is no download available at http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx for my AGP card. Only Windows drivers are available.

Should I go ahead and use the guide and manually install 12.1? I assume it's not on the amd website for a reason, but I was wondering if anybody had any experience with this. Thanks!

Comment: There seems to be no 12.1 version. The latest version for linux is 11.11, released on 01/25/2012 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Uri Herrera, I now have dual monitors, "one wide screen". (drag file from one screen to the other) in Precise 12.04. Here is what I had to do:

Boot to the *Recovery Mode.*  You'll see the menu (Resume, Network, etc.).

Scroll down to *Network* and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You should then get back to the menu. If not, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Scroll to *Drop to Root...*.

```
$ rm xorg.conf
$ apt-get install fglrx (Ubuntu Supported Binary driver -ATI-based)
$ reboot
```

Reboot to full graphics  mode.  Once both screens are live, go to *Settings* and click on *Display*. You see both of your displays. Click *ON* for each.

Two things to note:

1. Check the resolution for each one. Normally you'll want this to be the same setting for each monitor. However I have a 1929x1200 ("24" DIV) and a 1920x1080 (23" HDMI). So I have each monitor configured to its maximum resolution. Be careful, however, with that setup as when you drag a folder/file from the larger screen to the lesser it can get "stuck" (bothersome...but if so, just double click to get it back).
2. I chose my Left (Acer) Monitor for my Launcher Placement. This gives a full wide screen display and the icons only show on the far left (Acer). I'll post a pic (if I can) when I login.

Answer (score 0):

I am by FAR no expert.  But I've learned that AMD's Catalyst version for Linux is updated towards the end of each month.  The current version for linux is Catalyst 12.3 (March 2012)
Probably the easiest route is search for "AMD Catalyst for Linux" -- you can download from there.  Just don't try to install it over top of gflrx.
Cheers

Comment: AMD Catalyst driver *is* FGLRX.

Answer (score 0):

AMDs Catalyst 12.3 can be downloaded from here: http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx

Whether or not the bus (AGP in your case) plays a role in whether or not the driver can be used, I don't know. But is there a specific reason why you want to manually install the driver? Because you can install directly from the Ubuntu Software Center by clicking here: http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/fglrx-amdcccle. Afterwards you'll need to reboot. Then you can find AMD Catalyst Control Center in the Dash. (Entering 'cat' will most likely show it to you.)

Comment: No it doesn't matter if its AGP or PCI or PCI-e, what matters is the chip, the GPU model, as for his card it is still supported.